# Convert function to arrow function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert function into arrow function but it doesn't work. Am I doing some mistake my code is below. Kindly Guide me Where I am doing Mistake.

```js
// Call Back Function 
function ask(question, yes, no) { 
    if (confirm(question)){
        yes()
    } else {
        no()
    }
}

function showOk() {
    console.log("you agreed")
}

function showCancel() {
    console.log("canceled")
}

ask("do you agree ?", showOk, showCancel)


// Arrow Function

let ask = (question, yes, no) => {
    if (confirm(question)) {
        yes()
    } else {
        no()
    }

    let showOk = () => console.log("you agreed");

    let showCancel = () => console.log("Canceled");
}

ask("do you agree ?", showOk, showCancel)
```

Comment: `const ask = (question,yes,no) => confirm(question) ? yes() : no();`

Comment: And yeah, you are declaring `showOk` and `showCancel` inside the scope of `ask` in your poorly formatted code. Should get a `showOk is not defined error` - has nothing to do with arrow functions.

Comment: You don't close the `ask` function until after you declare `showCancel`. See the last curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

You have a curly bracket to late.

A shorter approach is to use the functions with a conditional statement.

```js
const
    ask = (question, yes, no) => (confirm(question) ? yes : no)(),
    showOk = () => console.log("you agreed"),
    showCancel = () => console.log("Canceled");

ask("do you agree ?", showOk, showCancel);
```

Comment: He has curly bracket *missing*, not too early.

Comment: @RoboRobok - actually the curly bracket is too late, not too early.

Comment: @Adam it's missing in `ask()` arrow version. Yeah, it's too late as it's seen later.

Comment: `(confirm(question) ? yes : no)()` would be better as `confirm(question) ? yes() : no()` - that parentheses shifting makes it confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably throwing a ReferenceError because showOk and showCancel are declared IN the scope of the arrow function, not globallly.

Answer (score -1):

For an arrow function to have an implicit return expression is required, 
so for each function, you have to return something, at least `return true` if you use {}.

Your code will look like

```
let ask = (question, yes, no) => {
  if (confirm(question)) {
      return yes();
   }
   return no();
}

let showOk = () => {
  console.log("you agreed");
  return true;
};

let showCancel = () => {
    console.log("Canceled");
  return true;
};

ask("do you agree ?", showOk, showCancel);
```

Comment: Why do you think an arrow function should return anything?

Comment: Functions, arrow or not, don’t have to return anything. Also, you are confusing “one line” arrow functions that implicitly return. Arrow functions can still use braces and in that case they don’t implicitly return. None of this has anything to do with the question, though.